# Powershell access lists in Active Directory

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a function `GrantGenericRead` that works when I create an object `$ouUnixGroups` in the same run. I'm trying to figure out how to get an object out of AD that I can run `GrantGenericRead` on, but it seems when I try this every way I know how (adsi, lookup using .Path), I can't access some property of the object to set it. I would love for someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

This code works when it's all run at the same time:

```
function CreateADGroup([string] $server, [string] $name, [string] $container, [string] $gtype)
{
    $objClass = "group";
    $strCn = GetCn -name $name -objClass $objClass;
    $objDsGroup  = CreateDsObject -server $server -container $container -name $name -objClass $objClass 
    [Void] $objDsGroup.Put("sAMAccountName", $name)
    if ($gtype -eq "global")
    {
        # Global Distribution Group 
        [Void] $objDsGroup.Put("groupType", 0x80000002)
    }
    elseif ($gtype -eq "dlg")
    {
        # Domain Local Distribution Group  
        [Void] $objDsGroup.Put("groupType", 0x80000004)
    }
    elseif ($gtype -eq "uni")
    {
        # Universal Security Group 
        [Void] $objDsGroup.Put("groupType", 0x80000008)
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host("Invalid group type {0}" -f $gtype)
    }
    [Void]$objDsGroup.SetInfo()
    return $objDsGroup
}

function CreateDsObject([string] $server, [string] $container, [string] $name, [string] $objClass)
{
$strConatinerPath = GetLdapPath -server $server -dn $container
$objContainer = [adsi] $strConatinerPath
$strChildCn = GetCn -name $name -objClass $objClass
$strChildDn = "{0},{1}" -f $strChildCn, $container
$strChildPath = GetLdapPath -server $server -dn $strChildDn
$objChildEntry = $objContainer.Create($objClass, $strChildCn)
[Void]$objChildEntry.SetInfo()
    return $objChildEntry
}

function GrantGenericRead($dsTrustee, $dsResources)
{
    $strSid = GetSid -dsObj $dsTrustee
    $objSid = New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($strSid)
    $ace = New-Object DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($objSid, $AD_RIGHT::GenericRead, $AC_TYPE::Allow)
    [Void] $dsResources.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($ace)
    [Void] $dsResources.psbase.CommitChanges()
}

function GetSid($dsObj)
{
    $dn = $dsObj.distinguishedName.Value
    $binary = $dsObj.psbase.Properties["objectSid"].Value
    $sid = New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($binary, 0)
    return $sid.ToString()
}

$adminContainerDn = "OU=Zone Administration,{0}" -f   $adminContainer.Get("distinguishedName") #returns OU=Zone Administration,OU=asdfasdf,DC=baldur,DC=vm
$ouUnixGroups   = CreateDsObject -server $server -container $ouDN -name $strOuUnixGroups   -objClass "OrganizationalUnit"
$joinOps = CreateADGroup -server $server -name "Join Operators" -container $adminContainerDn -gtype "global"

GrantGenericRead -dsTrustee $joinOps -dsResources $ouUnixGroups
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is being able to modify `$joinOps` and `$ouUnixGroups` from scripts that don't create them. How do I access them? I can get the sid, but that doesn't seem to help me, unless I'm missing something really key here.

```
GrantGenericRead -dsTrustee $joinOps -dsResources [adsi]$ouUnixGroups.Path
```

I'm pulling some of these lines out of an installer script that I have posted on http://pastebin.com/uF3nrDuw if anyone would like to have a look. u

Answer (score 1):

You can just try :

```
GrantGenericRead -dsTrustee [adsi]"cn=Agroup,ou=AnOU,dc=dompn,dc=domp0" -dsResources [adsi]"ou=theUnixOU,ou=AnOtherOU,dc=dompn,dc=domp0"
```

Comment: I'm afraid I tried that

PS C:\Windows\system32> GrantGenericRead -dsTrustee [adsi]$joinOps.Path -dsResources [adsi]$ouUnixGroups.Path
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:4 char:40
+     $binary = $dsObj.psbase.Properties[ <<<< "objectSid"].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (objectSid:String) [], Runtime
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

It appears to fall down here, in the getSid method:

[adsi]$ouUnixGroups.Path.psbase.objectsecurity.AddAccess
Rule($ace)

Comment: First to be sure to understand, the code you provide here works to create a group and an OU, you just want to use GrantGenericRead aginst existing objects ? Have you tried first to hard code DN strings of the existing objects ?

Comment: It works if I have the object in memory, as in if I create the group and the OU during this run. If I try it say, from the command line later. It doesn't work. I've tried hard coding the DN strings, and using adsi to look them up then storing them, still no dice. I don't get what I'm losing when I call the object from AD vs create it.

Comment: [Void] $dsResources.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($ace)

That is the line it bails on, from the grantGenericRead method.